# Profiling C++ with Xcode Instruments 7.0.1 - Demangling Symbol Names

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, instruments, xcode-instruments

**Note**: This is ***not*** a question regarding general usage of Xcode Instruments; I am already aware of how to use this application from the gui and command line.

When viewing `.dtps` profile data through Instruments for a command line `C++` application generated by `iprofiler`, is there any way to view demangled symbol names *in the displayed call tree*? I have searched through the `man` pages for `iprofiler`, and there does not seem to be anything regarding demangling symbol names at the time the profiling data is generated.

I have already tried compiling with debug symbols using `-g3`, but this does not seem to change anything within the Instruments application (i.e., Instruments does not seem to take advantage of this automatically, if it is possible for it to do so at all).

For reference, I am using Apple's distribution of `clang++` LLVM version 7.0.0 targeting x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0.